# Getting elements from linking table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that assign elements to groups. Each element can exist in many groups and can be assigned few times to the same group

it looks like:

```
element | group
      1 | 1
      1 | 2 
      1 | 3
      2 | 1
      2 | 3
      3 | 2
```

I'm looking for a simple query that can return me elements that are assigned to group 1, but NOT to group 2.

According to the presented data above this will be element 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct element 
from  your_table
where element not in (select element 
                      from your_table 
                      where `group` = 2)
and `group` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table` t2
   ON t1.element = t2.element
   AND t2.`group` = 2
WHERE t1.`group` = 1
   AND t2.`group` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
select element from table 
where group = 1 and not exists 
(select element from table t 
 where t.element=table.element and t.group = 2)
```